# update PHP code from within javascript using AJAX and setInterval

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, highcharts

On a webpage I have PHP and javascript code. Based off of the current date and time the PHP code assigns values to variables which are then used as arguments for functions in HighCharts (I'm using [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/dynamic-update/) code as a basis). Then using my PHP arguments my HighCharts code creates a plot which I want to update every X seconds.

Also I would like to keep my PHP code in the same file as my javascript code.

I can't get anything to work.

I'm open to using AJAX, PHP, Javascript, jQuery, and Highcharts functions

My best attempt thus far is the following:

```
<?php
function PHPfunc(){
/* create some variables that are function of the current date and time */
};
?>
<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:800px;"></div>
<script>
var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
      chart: {
         renderTo: 'container',
         zoomType: 'x'
         events : {
              load : function() {
                 var X = 5; //reload the PHP every 5 seconds
                 setInterval($.ajax({ 
                                 url: document.URL,
                                 data: {action: 'PHPfunc'},
                                 type: 'post',
                             }), X*1000);
         }
        }
       },
  /* PHP variables called */
});
</script>
```

I feel like wrapping the entire PHP code in a PHP function is the easiest thing to do and then call it with AJAX for X times but I can't get it to work.

Any corrections would be very appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: php and js run on different computers (php - the server, js - the users pc), at different times (php before output sent to browser, js after), so you simply cannot do what you suggest. You could simply reload the page using `settimout` and `location.reload(false)` but the correct solution would be to remove the inline php from your js, and instead load the data via ajax

Comment: You may have a fundamental misunderstanding of how PHP and JavaScript work. PHP is a server-side language while JavaScript (usually) is a client-side language. Client-side javascript is able to "communicate" with PHP with AJAX. When you request a PHP file from a web server, the web server uses a PHP interpreter to output the document as HTML, JavaScript, and CSS. The client has no way of interacting with the PHP directly. Also, once the PHP has finished rendering, the connection between the web server and the client closes (which is why AJAX was invented).

Comment: I recommend you to familiar with json to communicate your javascirpt and php sides. As @Jason said, you need to different a server side layer and javascirpt.